# Запуск события на определенном блоке при скролле с использованием malihu custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

[В продолжение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731468/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D1%81-animate-css).

Использую плагин [malihu custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)

Есть такая простейшая структура:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var container = $('#container');  
    
  container.mCustomScrollbar({
         axis:"x",
            theme:"dark-3",
            // scrollbarPosition: 'outside',
            advanced:{ autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true },
            autoScrollOnFocus: true,

            callbacks:{
              whileScrolling:function(){
                var 
                windowWidth = $(window).width(),
                    thisLeft, 
                    thisWidth;

                $('section').each(function(){
                  thisLeft = $(this).offset().left;
                  thisWidth = $(this).width();

                  if(thisLeft < windowWidth ){
                    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                  }else{

                  }
                });

              }
            }
        });   
  
});
```

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.js-page-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">


<div class="js-page-scroll" id="container">
  <main>
    <section id="item-1">
      <h2>1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-2">
      <h2>2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-3">
      <h2>3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-4">
      <h2>4</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-5">
      <h2>5</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

Суть проблемы в том, что при доскролле до секции должен выводится ее номер (в консоле) единожды, т.е при обратном скролле ничего в консоле не выводить.

Конкретная задача с реализацией TweenMax:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var thisLeft, thisWidth;
  
  
  
  function animateBlocks(){
    // $('.animated').each(function(){
    //   thisLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    //   thisWidth = $(this).width();
    //   if(thisLeft < windowWidth ){
    //      $(this).addClass('fadeInUp');
    //   }else{
    //     $(this).removeClass('fadeInUp');
    //   }
    // });
    
    $('h2').each(function(){
      var title = $(this);
      
      thisLeft = $(this).offset().left;
      thisWidth = $(this).width();
      
      if(thisLeft < windowWidth ){
        
        TweenMax.fromTo(
          title, 
          1,
          {scale: 0}, 
          {scale: 1, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.5)}
        );
        
      }else{
        //$(this).removeClass('fadeInUp');
      }
    });
  }
  
  animateBlocks();
  
 // Horizontal scroll
  var container = $('.js-page-scroll');
  
    if(container.length){
        container.mCustomScrollbar({
         axis:"x",
            theme:"dark-3",
            // scrollbarPosition: 'outside',
            advanced:{ autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true },
            autoScrollOnFocus: true,

            callbacks:{
                    whileScrolling:function(){
                     
                     animateBlocks();
                        
                    }
                }
        });
    }
  
  
  $(document).on("click","a[href^='#']",function(e){
    var href=$(this).attr("href"),target=$(href).parents(".mCustomScrollbar"); 
    if(target.length){
      e.preventDefault();
      target.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",href);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.js-page-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}


.horizontal-wow {
    visibility: hidden;
    animation-name: null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  
<menu>
  <a href="#item-1">it-1</a>
  <a href="#item-2">it-2</a>
  <a href="#item-3">it-3</a>
  <a href="#item-4">it-4</a>
  <a href="#item-5">it-5</a>
</menu>

<div class="js-page-scroll" id="container">
  <main>
    <section id="item-1">
      <h2>1</h2>
      <p class="animated" data-wow="fadeInUp">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-2">
      <h2>2</h2>
      <p class="animated" data-wow="fadeInLeft">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-3">
      <h2>3</h2>
      <p class="animated" data-wow="slideInUp">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-4">
      <h2>4</h2>
      <p class="animated" data-wow="bounce">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-5">
      <h2>5</h2>
      <p class="animated" data-wow="zoomIn">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** Как, при скролле, запускать событие соответствующего блока единожды (добавить класс или вывести сообщение в консоли)?

Для конкретного случая - запуск tweenMax единожды при достижении определенного блока, при обратном скролле - отмена (не запускать еще раз tweenmax).

Т.е. запуск анимации, добавление класс, alert и прочее только раз после загрузки при скролле вперед и при попадании на определенный блок (есди section-1 - console.log(item-1) \ tweenmax1 , и т.д ...).

Comment: Переменная, которая принимает true, если скролл больше/ false если меньше и условие "если скролл больше и переменная равна false"

Comment: а если второй раз скролл вперёд идёт?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, без перезагрузки, то ничего так же если и назад. Т.е. запуск анимации, добавление класс, alert и прочее только раз после загрузки при скролле вперед и при попадании на определенный блок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение: добавлять на каждый блок атрибут `done='true'` при первом запуске.

Далее на запуск функции проверяем выставлен ли атрибут, если выставлен, то ничего не делаем, если не выставлен - вызываем функцию и устанавливаем `done='true'`.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var container = $('#container');  
    
  container.mCustomScrollbar({
         axis:"x",
            theme:"dark-3",
            // scrollbarPosition: 'outside',
            advanced:{ autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true },
            autoScrollOnFocus: true,

            callbacks:{
              whileScrolling:function(){
                var 
                windowWidth = $(window).width(),
                    thisLeft, 
                    thisWidth;

                $('section').each(function(){
                  thisLeft = $(this).offset().left;
                  thisWidth = $(this).width();

                  if(thisLeft < windowWidth ){
                    if(!this.getAttribute("done")) {

                      console.log($(this).attr('id'));

                      this.setAttribute("done",true);
                    }
                  }else{

                  }
                });

              }
            }
        });   
  
});
```

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.js-page-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">


<div class="js-page-scroll" id="container">
  <main>
    <section id="item-1">
      <h2>1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-2">
      <h2>2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-3">
      <h2>3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-4">
      <h2>4</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="item-5">
      <h2>5</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все гениальное - просто!) Награду через пару дней отдам!

Comment: @HamSter пожалуйста!